# Stray start tag - validation error

Tags: validation

While trying to validate my website i encountered this error message.

```
Error: Stray start tag script.
From line 450, column 1; to line 450, column 74
Code -->↩<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></s
```

I have no other errors, and all code is contained within the body tag.

My document ends at line 447 so where is this line 450 the error refers to?

and why does it mention my web host? i'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that your web host is modifying your HTML (in this case it appears they are adding some kind of JavaScript tracking script at the very end of the document, after your `</html>` tag) before serving it.

Comment: Can i do anything about this or should i change host?

Comment: @Wayne — "Can i do anything about this" — You'd need to ask your how about that.